# Chrome not displaying embedded video using <script> tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, embed

I am trying to embed and share a video from another site on a webpage. When I click on the embed link where the video is currently hosted, it gives me a `<script src="URL"></script>` tag. This seems to be working in all browsers except Google Chrome. For some reason in Goolge Chrome the content collapses where the video player should be. Also, this works fine when locally hosted, only when loaded to the web does it not display in Chrome. Any thoughts?

Here is the code given by the embed link:
    `<script src="http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?video_pcode=Jpc2U6ifuN3N3ebMRnOK62_dEZgI&embedCode=twOGdrMzotaRAsx2uW77KOgUFXCokf5p&width=640&deepLinkEmbedCode=twOGdrMzotaRAsx2uW77KOgUFXCokf5p&height=360"></script>`

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the share code the video gives you?

Comment: If you could post the code on http://jsfiddle.net/, that'd make it much easier for us to help :-)

Comment: @ Little Big Bot, I've posted the given code above.

Comment: @ misterkeg - here is a link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keithiopian/eezGk/

Comment: It's working fine for me in Chrome. I'm on a Mac, though.

Comment: Ok, so latest development, the reason it is not loading is because the landing page is https and the video is coming from and http page, thus it is automatically being blocked by Chrome. Much like with IE popping up with a warning asking if you want to display secure and non-secure elements, Chrome is automatically not displaying. If anyone knows a work around to allow content to display, please let me know. Unfortunately though, I have a feeling this is just the way things are. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a dig and it looks like you're right about the http/https mismatch, but it's on Ooyala's side.

However, I found this:
http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/concepts/player_v3_dev_embedcode_diff.html

It mentions that v3 of the player (which you appear to not be using currently) supports both protocols.

The link mentions that in order to use v3, you'll need to add a player branding ID, which is unique to each video. Is this something you have access to?

Hope this helps!